# Php Regular Expression repeated characters

Tags: php, regex

I have a string in php like this.

$str = "ABCCCDE"  //Contains repeated character CCC more than 2 times

I want to know if there is any repeated characters more than 2 times using regular expression.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('/(.)\\1{2}/', $str))
   echo "Has 3 same characters consecutively!";
```

The `(.)` will match any character (except new lines), and the `\1` will match a pattern same as the first matched group — in this case, the character we've just matched. So this RegEx will match 3 same consecutive characters.

Comment: It returns 1 when there is string "abccde". It should return 1 only there is a repeated character more than 2 times

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
'/(.)\1\1/'
```

E.g.:

```
preg_match('/(.)\1\1/', $str, $matches);
```