# How to check if string contains just 1 same number

Tags: php, string, phone-number

I've got a Call Me Back form which sends me a phone number of a person who wants to be called back. Today I received the form with '88888888' instead of a real phone number.

How can I check if the string contains 1 and the same number, continous? 
There must not be more than 4 same numbers in a row.

Comment: This is going to piss off anyone who, for whatever reason, has a legit number with 4 consecutive identical digits. And it's going to do nothing for whoever sent you 88888888; next time they 'll send 12345678.

Comment: Assuming you want to validate a North American telephone number: [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357675/validating-us-phone-number-with-php-regex).

Comment: Don't try and validate telephone numbers just like you should never try and validate names. That said, `/^(\d)\1+$/`

Comment: @couzzi Actually I am trying to check a Dutch phone number :). It's not that I want to fully validate it, just check if it has just got 1 number in it, which continous (8888888888 or 5555555555, 444444444 etc)

Comment: Please reconsider this question's duplicate status: [The answer noted above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792908/php-regular-expression-repeated-characters) has solutions that match *consecutive* characters, regardless of the beginning or end of the string. OP seeks a solution which determines if a string contains *one exclusive* character *repeatedly*. For example, [The suggested answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792908/php-regular-expression-repeated-characters) would fail for `88888889`, amongst many others.

Answer (score 3):

To check if the string contains only **one** repeated integer, string -> array, check if the unique count is 1.

```
<?php

$string  = "88888888"; 

$array = array_unique( str_split( $string ) );

$result = $array;

if( count($result) === 1 ) {
    echo "Same number repeated in string";
}else{
    echo "More than 1 number found in string";
}

?>
```

-Edit-

optimized: Removed `for` loop thanks to comment by @Uberfuzzy

Comment: You can kill your `for` loop by using [str_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php).  `$array = array_unique( str_split( $string ) );`

Comment: This worked great for me thanks! You can also kill the $length variable (I'm assuming it was used in the for loop that was removed).

Answer (score 1):

```
$number_string = (string)$number_string;
return strlen($number_string) > 0 && str_repeat($number_string[0], strlen($number_string)) === $number_string;
```