# PHP how to check there are more than 2 running same chars in a string

Tags: php, char

checking if a string has more than running one occurrence of same character. 
like `iiiiiiii` or `ssssss`. maybe use preg_match but what pattern it should be?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Read about back-references in a regular expression tutorial. http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792908/php-regular-expression-repeated-characters

Comment: no didnt try anything, thanks @ Daimos.. any one can give me good reference about how to create patterns with many examples cuz i am so bad @ this  thanks barmar for the reference as well :)

Answer (score 3):

Try with this regex:

```
$str = 'hello';
print preg_match('/([\w])\1{1,}/', $str); /*return true */
```